# Can I use GET method instead of POST method in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, get

In SpringMVC if suppose I can use POST method instead of the GET method, and it works. Then what is the purpose of these methods and how can we differentiate these methods?

Answer (score 2):

As default browser requests pages and other resources using GET method.

If you using [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) for some kind of web-service you may use GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and HEAD request (and some others).

**GET** method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect.

**POST** method requests that the server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the web resource identified by the URI.

**PUT** method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied URI. If the URI refers to an already existing resource, it is modified; if the URI does not point to an existing resource, then the server can create the resource with that URI.

**DELETE** method deletes the specified resource.

**HEAD** method asks for a response identical to that of a GET request, but without the response body. This is useful for retrieving meta-information written in response headers, without having to transport the entire content.